# Bootstrap - add dropdown menu (language switcher)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Im using bootstrap 3.3.7 in my test project. This is the production link:
http://colorfill.ionic.host/test/

As you will notice in the top right corner there is a LANG dropdown menu. While hovering it display somehow the content but it looks like the z-index was to small. Increasing it - change nothing.

I'm using following code:

```
<ul class="social pull-right">  

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" title="Language" class="icon-request">LANG:</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu zom">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">POL</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="index2.html">ENG</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="index3.html">UA</a></li>
                                    </ul><!-- /.dropdown-menu -->                               
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-s-facebook"></i></a></li>                            
                        </ul>
```

what is wrong then? should I write my own .dropdown class? I dont want to destroy current nav menu..

Answer (score 2):

add style for parent div that have **navbar-header** class as

```
  <div class="navbar-header" style=" z-index: 1;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the `z-index` of `.navbar-header` to `1`, currently its `0`. Like:

```
.navbar-header {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

> You need to increase the z-index of the parent element, no matter what
>   your child z-index is, If your parent's z-index is lower than child's
>   it will not work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

add this `css` code to `custom.css` in `line9`:

```
.navbar-header {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to **.navbar-header**  `z-index: 1;`